# What "meta" means?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm a new user on `ask ubuntu` and beginner on `linux` too, this is my first question:

What is the meaning of `meta`?

---

I found this page on wikipedia "[Meta - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)" but I'm not sure if it explain `meta` well.

Answer (score 8):

*Meta* is the Greek word for beyond.

... as for Ask Ubuntu Meta we have a good explanation already - its a good read!

- https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta